# State is Empty but the Action is loading the data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello I am quick new with React Redux,

I am working on a React Landing page calling an AirTable API to learn. And since two, I am completely stuck with the data rendering from my store. As we can see, thanks to the redux console, the data is loaded:
[image: Redux Console]

But I am not able to call in my containers. When I console logs data, I have an empty arrayx
[image: Chrome Console]

Here is my action:

```js
export const FETCH_DATAS = 'FETCH_DATAS';

export function fetchDatas() {
  const promise = fetch('API').then(response => response.json());

  return {
    type: FETCH_DATAS,
    payload: promise
 };

}
```

Here is my reducer

```js
import { FETCH_DATAS }  from '../actions';

export default function (state =[], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATAS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is my index.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../assets/stylesheets/application.scss';
import {
  Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import history from './components/history';
import Growths from "./components/pages/Growths";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose  } from 'redux';
import datasReducer from './reducers/index.js';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';


const reducers = combineReducers({
  datas: datasReducer,
  form: formReducer
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const middlewares = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxPromise, logger));

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, middlewares);




ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

And here my container

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ContentLeft from './ContentLeft.jsx';
import ContentRight from './ContentRight.jsx';
import NavBar from './NavBar.jsx';
import Hero from './Hero.jsx';
import DotsNavigation from './DotsNavigation.jsx';
import Slide from 'react-reveal/Slide';
import '../../../assets/stylesheets/PageList.scss';
import logo from '../../../assets/img/logo-white.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDatas } from '../../actions/index.js'

class PageList extends Component{

   componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchDatas();
 }

  render() {
      console.log(this.props.datas);
      return (
        <>
        <DotsNavigation
          items={this.props.items}
          key='Dots'
             />
        <Slide bottom>
          <Hero
            items={this.props.items}
            key='Hero'
           />
        </Slide>

          <ContentLeft
            items={this.props.items}
            key='ContentLeft'
           />

          <ContentRight
            items={this.props.items}
            key='ContentRight'
           />
        </>

      );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  datas: state.datas
 };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ fetchDatas }, dispatch);
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageList);
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Warm Regards and thanks for your help

Comment: Please take a look at redux-saga to handle side effects like api calls with redux - https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: You are dispatching action with payload of promise, it is not the way to do it - you eaither await the result and then dispatching or you dispatching in .then of promise.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic

Answer (score 0):

you have to use redux middleware such as redux-thunk
let me show you what i mean:
first apply redux thunk to your code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';


const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

then go to your action file and edit this

```
export const fetchDatas = () => async (
   dispatch
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('API').then(response => response.json());
});

dispatch({
  type: FETCH_DATAS  ,
  payload: response.data,
});
 } catch (err) {
       dispatch({
          type: ERROR  ,
         payload: error.response.data,
  });
  }
};
```

and i recommend to use axios for interact with Api instead of fetch